# Element created in constructor not updated when component rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, ecmascript-6

Why is the `<select>` I create in the constructor not updated when I pick another flavor in it? The other `select`, as well as the text, is updated.

```js
class ConstructorComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      icecream: 'vanilla',
    };
    
    this.select = (
      <select
        value={this.state.icecream}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      >
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
  
  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      icecream: event.target.value,
    });
  };
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Icecream flavor: {this.state.icecream}
        <br />
        {this.select}
        <br />
        <select
          value={this.state.icecream}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        >
          <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
          <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
          <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ConstructorComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

I made it work by cloning `this.select` in `render()` like so: `{React.cloneElement(this.select, {value: this.state.icecream})}`

But making `this.select` a method instead, as suggested by several answers to my question is probably better. I'll see what works best with my actual code, and not just this dumbed down example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this.state.icecream` in your first select is interpreted only once, when you define `this.select` in the constructor. So when your `ConstructorComponent` rerenders a second time when its state changes, there is nothing to update in your first select.

You need to define `this.select` as a function returning the `<select>`, like this:

```
this.select = () => {
  return (
    <select
      value={this.state.icecream}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    >
      <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
      <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
      <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

And call `this.select()` in the render.

**You can also create a reference to the `<select>` in the render by using the prop `ref`**:

```
render() {
  <select
    value={this.state.icecream}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    ref={select => (this.select = select)}  // the magic happens here
  >
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
  </select>
}
```

In doing so, you don't need to define `this.select` as a function in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The first select doesn't work because it's only ever rendered once, in the constructor. The second select works because it's re-rendered every time the app state updates.

If it helps, don't think of JSX elements as "instances" of actual HTML elements. Think of them as a simple means of how you want your app to look in relation to your state. If my state is "a", then I render a select with "a", and if my state is "b", then I render a select with "b", and so on.

Comment: So, the obvious follow-up question; How do I make it re-render? :)

Comment: The most obvious way I could think of would be to make it a function which returns the JSX, then call that function in render. Though here it would probably be simplest to write the JSX in render, like you've done with the second one. I imagine there's a reason you can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

The first select box on the page is only rendered in the constructor which is called just once, thus the component will always remain the same as it does when it is first rendered. In other words it is static. The second select box is going to be re-rendered each time the component is updated.

In order to fix your code you can change your line in the constructor to a function:

```
this.select = () => (
  <select
    value={this.state.icecream}
    onChange={this.onChange}
  >
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
  </select>
);
```

Then change your return statement to call this function:

```
<br />
  {this.select()}
<br />
```